# Pass-through of Marvell 88SE9230 to Xen guest with AMD-V iommu

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, xen, virt-manager

I have a Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P board with a AMD FX(tm)-8350 cpu. I have IOMMU enabled in the BIOS. 
For the non-XEN linux boot I pass `iommu=pt amd_iommu_dump` as a kernel argument and can verify that AMD-V is loaded via `dmsg | grep AMD-V`.
When running a QEMU/**KVM** guest I can passthrough the Marvell 88SE9230 card to the guest and *everything works fine*.

*I want to get this pass-through working with a **XEN** setup as well*.
However from the 4 SATA 0-3 ports that the 88SE9230 card supplies only the last port is actually discovering a disk (i.e. if port 0 and 1 are connected, then disk on port 1 is discovered, while port 0 remains empty).

I now run `Xen 4.9` via `apt-get install xen-hypervisor-4.9-amd64` in an Ubuntu-18.04 dom0. Kernel is `4.15.0-29-generic`. I rebind my device (in my case 0000:01:00.0) via pciback.sh as described [here](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_PCI_Passthrough#Dynamic_assignment_with_sysfs_.28when_xen-pciback_is_loaded_as_a_module_and_NOT_compiled_into_the_kernel.29) and rebind via `pciback.sh "0000:01:00.0"`. Then I can attach 0000:01:00.0 to the Xen guest.

Inside the guest `0000:01:00.0` appears and `lspci` and `pciconf` (in my case the XEN guest is FreBSD FreeNAS) works correctly. However only the disk on the last connected port is detected. All other ports seems to be empty even if I have a disk connected. In the KVM version these disks are recognized.

I was wondering where the AMD iommu handling is implemented in the Xen case. The Ubuntu 18.04 dom0 doesnt have any iommu entries in sysfs and the AMD-V debug messages are not printed. So I guess there is a baremetal XEN hypervisor that implements the iommu initialization. Is there some option I need to add to enable AMD iommu handling in the hypervisor (equivalent to the linux `iommu=pt` option) and how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Xen emulated IDE will appear as ada0 while the passthrough SATA device will also appear as ada0. This results in one disk shadowing the other. In /dev/ only one ada0 entry will be seen.